# Supporting Multiple Screens for some devices in Android

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I read the official document about supporting multiple screens http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

According to that document, I should just create different directories for different resolultion.

Now the question. How to support devices with normal screen and high density or low density?

I ask it because, there are two posibilities (WVGA800 (480x800) and WVGA854 (480x854)) and (WQVGA400 (240x400) and WQVGA432 (240x432)) and I don't know where to store some background images for them.

I would take drawable-normal-hdpi or drawable-normal-ldpi, but how to make difference between 480x800 and 480x854 or between 240x400 and 240x432?!

Thank you in advance,

Mur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) on how to specify alternate resources.

So you could do `drawable-normal-hdpi` for medium screens with high dpi.

Comment: Why drawable-medium-hdpi? I would take drawable-normal-hdpi or drawable-normal-ldpi, but how to make difference between 480x800 and 480x854 or between 240x400 and 240x432?!

Comment: @mur Sorry, that was a typo on my part, supposed to be "normal" not medium.  I don't think you can differentiate between actual resolution sizes.  They have the same width (or double, but it is almost the same aspect ratio), it's just there might be some slight height difference (30-50pixels).  They're close enough that if your layout scales (with 9 patch images or other non-absolute layouts) that it shouldn't matter *that*  much.

Answer (score -1):

you have to specify layout folder like following:-

```
layout-small-ldpi (240x320)  
layout-small-land-ldpi (320x240)

layout-ldpi  (240 x 400 )
layout-land-ldpi  (400 x 240 )

layout-mdpi (320 x 480 )
layout-land-mdpi (480 x 320 )

layout-large-mdpi (320 x 480 )
layout-large-land-mdpi (480 x 320)

layout-large  (600 x 1024)
layout-large-land  (1024 x 600)

layout-hdpi (480 x 800)
layout-land-hdpi (800 x 480)

layout-xlarge (800 x 1280)
layout-xlarge-land (1280 x 800)
```