# How to set my .apk file to run on different screen resolution in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen, android-layout, resolution

I am using a "WVGA800" for my app. I try to run it on different resolution screens. It it is not perfectly scratching in that resolution .
I read and implement issues form this link.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
But still not result. Please let me know if any one hase a perfect solution. 
Main issue are that I am fixing hight & width of Image, textsize etc. When these are displayed
to screen of "WVGA800". But when I test them on "HVGA", "QVGA" then problem arise.
I want to avoid the "if else" conditions by getting the screen resolution at Runtime. If any one hase any solution for this...let me know. Thanks in advance. 
I am also wondring when there will be new devices with new screen resolutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186177/supporting-multiple-screens-for-some-devices-in-android), may be its helpful for you.

Comment: I also implement this. Can you please tell me if I can have 4 copies of Row.XML  (for Listview row), can I put these to alternative resources? How I can?

Comment: If you want different resources for different densities, put them in hdpi, mdpi and ldpi folder respectively. See this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources.

Comment: Yes I have different resources. I have create an Layout.XML for different densities.!

Comment: I am placing my .xml    as following directory. Layout-small/    , layout-normal/,   layout-large/    . But On any device It use only normal .XML   file layout. How to handle this one?

Comment: Does this conforms to Android's standards?

Answer (score 1):

`Main issue are that I am fixing hight & width of Image, textsize etc`

Don't do that.

Comment: If I set it wrap_content then Image do not perfectly display on screen. As I am fetching the images form Net at runtime. So different image have different size? So in such a way Look of my ListView disturbe. As each item has its own image size?

Answer (score 1):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.your_company.package_name"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<supports-screens
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true"/>
.....
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below code into your manifest:-

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

and you must have to make different different layout folder with different screen:-

```
layout-small-ldpi (240x320)  
layout-small-land-ldpi (320x240)

layout-ldpi  (240 x 400 )
layout-land-ldpi  (400 x 240 )

layout-mdpi (320 x 480 )
layout-land-mdpi (480 x 320 )

layout-large-mdpi (320 x 480 )
layout-large-land-mdpi (480 x 320)

layout-large  (600 x 1024)
layout-large-land  (1024 x 600)

layout-hdpi (480 x 800)
layout-land-hdpi (800 x 480)

layout-xlarge (800 x 1280)
layout-xlarge-land (1280 x 800)
```